# PHP - SQLSRV Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

Lately I've been making a web app in PHP and using MySQL but days ago I've been told to migrate to SQL Server.

The problem is that I'm knew in programming and i know nothing about SQLServer.

I've took one morning to successful install xampp extension of SQLServer and then tried to look for the functions of connection, prepared statements...

In http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php I've discovered the functions and I did something like this:

```
$DB_Server = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$DB_User = "userName";
$DB_Password = "j$oeisk="; //The Password is something like this
$DB_Name = "databaseName";

global $DB_Server, $DB_User, $DB_Password, $DB_Name;

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $DB_User, "PWD" => $DB_Password, "Database"=>$DB_Name); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($DB_Server, $connectionInfo);

$result = NULL;

if ($conn)
{   
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    if (($Profile == 1) && ($stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "SELECT name FROM users")))
    {               
        if(sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ))
        {           
          echo "<select name='workers'>";

          while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))
          {
                echo "<option value=",$result['nome'],">",$result['nome'],"</option>";
          }

          echo "</select>";                         

          sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt );
         }

    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
    }   
}
```

But it shows me this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: oeisk in C:\xampp\htdocs\markings\database.php
```

I've been looking for solutions but I don't even imagine how it's done

I appreciate any help

Comment: Put single quotes around the password.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks it worked but $conn should return true and it doesn't. I can connect to the database through SqlDbx so it's functional but not throught PHP.  It's the sintax right this way?

Comment: The syntax looks fine, so there is something wrong with the credentials. Add an `else` and use `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true))` to see why the connection is not being made.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think I didn't proper installed the extension: This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Comment: Ah, ok. Install the driver on your server and make sure to restart it once you have it configured properly.